Desktop application on vm in a cluster: which windows OS?
We need to run Hec-Ras software (river flow calculations) on a virtual machine in a vmWare cluster. That software will be run by a person at a time and we will put on a vm only because we don't have workstations with the requested ram and disk space.
We are going to create that machine but we don't know whether it is better to use a Windows server OS or opt for Windows 11 Pro.
In fact that software is normally installed on workstations and in the release notes only desktop versions of windows are listed. I'm pretty sure it can run on windows server too and I wonder if there are reasons to prefer it over Windows 11 for this specific requirement.

Desktop Windows is difficult to license in virtual machine clusters. From a licensing standpoint you are much better off with a server version of Windows instead of desktop, if it is supported by the software.
